# Adding in a smooth fade in/out transition to background images

Tags: css, image, transition

I am trying to initiate a background image transition with multiple photos (I hope to make the duration last for about 15 seconds). Here is what I have so far in CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url('http://i.cubeupload.com/5sAFEq.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```css
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes images {
    0%   {background-image: url("http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg");}
      50%   {background-image: url("http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2012/09/02-11.jpg");}
  
    100% {background-image: url("https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99059361-choose-cat-litter-632x475.jpg"); }
}

#test {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 animation-name: images;
 animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-direction: normal;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 500px 500px; height: 500px; width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  </div>
```